# Referencing paths from a css element to another file

Tags: css, html

I'd like to be able to put all of my paths in one file ("property file"), so whenever I refernce them  , the provided functionality should imiplement:

### some_file.css

```
#facebook_link {
    background:url(../refereced_file/$facebook_link_url); // ?
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 12px;;
    height: 23px;
}
```

### refereced_file

```
$facebook_link_url : ../images/old/facebook.png
```

I'm aware, as a server-side developer (mostly), that the mechanism of the processing of the browser is different from a compiler, and yet, I want to be able to achieve the property file functionality ( "`propObject.getProperty(key)`").

I'm not using Saas or SCSS, nor CSS variables.

Thought of making another CSS file with an element and referencing to it, but have no idea how to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is either to use SAAS/SCSS or parsing the css file on your server and look for any variables which need to be replaced with a value from your property.